# Lagom publish entity events as Source for websocket connection

Tags: events, websocket, lagom

Is it possible (and if yes, how), to publish a stream of entity updates directly (without any additional topic) as Source returned from a service like this?

```
public ServiceCall<NotUsed, Source<EntityPublicEvent, ?>> entityUpdates()
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to consume those events in Angular 5 over websocket.

```
    @Override
        public ServiceCall<String, Source<EntityPublicEvent, ?>> getUpdateNotifications() {
            return request -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(updatesTopic.subscriber().map(this::convertEvent));
        }
```

I can see in Angular gets connected and the service is also called to return the Source but no updates are sent as messages to Angular.
There is also this line appearing in logs, which I suppose could be the reason why I cant get any messages in Angular:

> [info] akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
>   [sourceThread=currency-impl-application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3,
>   akkaTimestamp=06:59:55.778UTC,
>   akkaSource=akka://currency-impl-application/system/distributed
>   PubSubMediator, sourceActorSystem=currency-impl-application] - Message
>   [tcs.currency.impl.CurrencyEvent$Created] without sender to
>   Actor[akka://currency-impl-application/system/distributedPubSubMediator#128487187]
>   was  not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be
>   turned off or adjusted with configuration settings
>   'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, in this case my Angular component was creating the connection but not listening for messages. I was trying to start with the code provided here https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-websockets-tutorial/, which is an echo service and not just a simple listener.

With this simple code I'm now able to receive the update messages:

```
let subject = Observable.webSocket('ws://localhost:9000/ws/api/currency/updates');
    subject
      .retry()
      .subscribe(
      (msg) => console.log('message received: ' + msg),
      (err) => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('complete')
      );
```